# Changing the CRS of all shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance

I've just realised I've been using the wrong CRS for an analysis.

As I've done a fair bit of analysis (distance to nearest hub, transformation of lines into points etc), I was wondering if by setting the new CRS I need, it would update all the distances inside the shapefiles etc or do I have to run everything again?

For example, I have the distance of each city from a border, set in [ESPG::26985](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::26985), and I'd like to change it in [ESRI::53027](https://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/53027/ogcwkt/). I have this for 25 countries...

Comment: The impact will differ from projection to projection and from use case to use case but in general, if you modify the geometry of a shape file, you have to recalculate all attributes that you have calculated before the modification. If you reproject to a different CRS, I would suggest that recalucation is necessary too.

Comment: 53027 isn't a code in the EPSG database, it's an ESRI defined projection

Comment: @nmtoken would that be an issue? I've been suggested to use it as my area of interest is on a very large scale, spanning two continents. The equidistant conic projection was therefore useful to measure distances between two countries on different continents.

Comment: largely semantics.

Comment: Right. I've done a new analysis using the ESRI defined projection 53027, and it gives me an average difference of 8km between my former CRS and the new one.

Comment: What countries are you evaluating with a Maryland-centered projection? Your second projection might be wrong as well -- I wouldn't use an Authalic sphere for this either. Please provide the extent of your study area in degrees. Also, be careful of wanting to "change" projections -- this is not the same as reprojecting.

Comment: @Vince, the Maryland centred projection was for a former project, and I've started a new analysis and forgot to change the CRS. I'm focusing on all the coastal countries of the Mediterranean sea. The extent would be from top left corner: 43°12'26.7"N 1°50'48.7"W, bottom left: 27°41'42.3"N 13°09'45.1"W, top right: 41°27'36.7"N 41°30'50.9"E, bottom right: 3°25'28.9"S 39°49'19.9"E. I just need a rough estimation of the distance, even to a dozen kilometre.

Comment: I'm surprised a Maryland projection could produce any results whatsoever in the Med.

Comment: @Vince, it does actually, and by using the $length inside the field calculator, I obtain distances not far away from official distances from the coast of cities I am investigating. But I want to set a CRS that is better suited of course.

Comment: Unfortunately, that means your data is corrupt, and no longer has any ties to the actual spatial extent.

Comment: Yes that's why I need to set my new CRS and re-do all my calculations from scratch

Comment: Pretty much the only situation where *setting* a CRS is appropriate is when the CRS is undefined (and this shouldn't really happen in this millennium). Under most other situations, you should only *reproject* to change CRS. Setting a CRS does not change the data, just how it is processed, so setting a CRS inappropriately is effectively misrepresenting the data to the GIS software, in which case all your measurements are suspect. Instead asserting a new CRS that helps your calculations, you need to reapply the correct CRS to the data, then work from there.

Comment: Very helpful comments many thanks for your input